# transferring Bitcoins between two exchange

Tags: exchanges

I transferred my bitcoins from Binance to Yobit. The BTC are gone from Binance but it is not coming on Yobit.net. 
I also transferred Litecoin from GDAX to yobit. They are also not showing in Yobit. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have the transactions' IDs?

Comment: Wait or do something else. Check again in 12 hours or so.